# Multiple silverlight async calls and combobox source

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, combobox

I have 3 comboboxes and every combobox need different source. For every source I have WCF service and each service is called in the same time asynchronously. 
My problem is that every combobox is populated when the last service is completed, they are all waiting the longest service. I need to populate combobox when his service is complete.

My code:

```
public ArtiklViewModel Artikl;

public ItemNewEdit(ArtiklViewModel _artikl, bool _edit)
{
        InitializeComponent();

        Artikl = _artikl;

        SifarnikServiceClient service1 = new SifarnikServiceClient();
        service1.GetSifarniksByVrstaAsync(1);
        service1.GetSifarniksByVrstaCompleted += new EventHandler<GetSifarniksByVrstaCompletedEventArgs>(service_GetSifarniks1Completed);

        SifarnikServiceClient service2 = new SifarnikServiceClient();
        service2.GetSifarniksByVrstaAsync(2);
        service2.GetSifarniksByVrstaCompleted += new EventHandler<GetSifarniksByVrstaCompletedEventArgs>(service_GetSifarniks2Completed);

        SifarnikServiceClient service3 = new SifarnikServiceClient();
        service3.GetSifarniksByVrstaAsync(3);
        service3.GetSifarniksByVrstaCompleted += new EventHandler<GetSifarniksByVrstaCompletedEventArgs>(service_GetSifarniks3Completed);
}

    void service_GetSifarniks1Completed(object sender, GetSifarniksByVrstaCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        combo1.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
        if (Artikl != null)
            combo1.SelectedValue = Artikl.JmjID;
    }

    void service_GetSifarniks2Completed(object sender, GetSifarniksByVrstaCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        combo2.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
        if (Artikl != null)
            combo2.SelectedValue = Artikl.GrupaID;
    }

    void service_GetSifarniks3Completed(object sender, GetSifarniksByVrstaCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        combo3.ItemsSource = e.Result.ToList();
        if (Artikl != null)
            combo3.SelectedValue = Artikl.TarifaID;
    }
```

Comment: the fact that all the services will be disposed after the calls are made will be causing an issue.  I would personally try to use the async keyword to make the code simpler, if you have control of the SifarnikServiceClient this would be easier.

Comment: You are calling your services in the constructor.
The constructor executions is synchronous, it doesn't support async keyword.
Also, you haven't provided the signatures for the SifarnkServiceClient methods.

If they are async, then you can create a new delegate, hook that up to the page loading, and then the methods should be invoked correctly. Also, you should set up the eventhandlers BEFORE invoking the methods.

Comment: @zaitsman can you provide some code for your suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is a common problem with Xaml based UIs like Silverlight and UWP. The problem is that the standard Microsoft Selector controls are not async ready. They care about the order in which the ItemsSource, and the SelectedItem are set. I put a proposed solution up yesterday. It's quite complex, but comprehensive. You might want to take a look.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003805/uwp-silverlight-combobox-selector-itemssource-selecteditem-race-condition-solu